# Gestures in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, ios, iphone, gesture, xamarin.forms

How to swipe left,right,top and bottom gestures with xamarin.forms control?

I have worked all gestures separately in native platforms with renders it's too risky and too late output as well. Most of the people suggesting to purchase MR Gesture. Is it correct to work with MR Gesture or is there any other alternative with swipe in xamarin.forms?

Comment: hope this helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe. let me know if any query.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Forms only supports [Tap](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/gestures/) gestures.  To add support for swipe, you will either need to use a third party package like MRGestures, or write a platform [renderer](http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/) to handle them.

Comment: Hi Jason, i have purchased MRGestures it working fine with swipe ...its not giving proper output to rotate event..still some isuues are there with that also...he need to improve his package as well